# MYSQL where statements

Tags: mysql

I am making a system that checks connectivity on SSL adresses. For this, I use two tables:

```
ssllist
- id
- dnsname
- active (0 or 1)

sslresult
- id
- ssllist_id
- starttime
- result (0 or 1)
```

By default, my system checks all entries in ssllist every 30 minutes, but I also want it to check the entries every minute that match these rules:

```
- Active=1
AND(
  - no results of this entry in sslresult
OR
  - had an error in the last half hour (result=0)
OR
  - did not have ANY results in the last half hour
)
```

So, I made this query to comply to the first 3 rules:

```
SELECT
ssllist.id as id,
ssllist.dnsname
FROM ssllist
LEFT JOIN sslresult
ON ssllist.id = sslresult.ssllist_id
WHERE 
ssllist.active=1 
AND
(
  (sslresult.result = 0 AND sslresult.starttime > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 1800)  
  OR 
  sslresult.ssllist_id is null
)
GROUP BY id
```

However I don't know how to add the last "where" statement, so "get all ssllist.id's which DID NOT have a sslresult in the last half hour).

How to do that?

Comment: sample data with a corresponding expected results would be helpful